# How to use Typescript to define strongly typed email template parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

I have a number of different email templates that each have different parameters.

I can define a type for each template:

```
type TemplateType = 'welcomeEmail' | 'referralEmail' | 'loginEmail'
```

And for each template I can define parameters:

```
interface WelcomeEmail {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  ...
}
```

I a can then define an EmailTemplate interface:

```
interface EmailTemplate {
  template: TemplateType;
  params: WelcomeEmail | ReferralEmail | LoginEmail;
}
```

Is there a way to type this so that when the template is 'welcomeEmail' the `params` type is `WelcomeEmail`?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in recent versions of Typescript if you change your types around a bit. This works by sourcing the `TemplateType` and the `EmailTemplate` from the same `EmailTemplates` type. Typescript knows that members of `TemplateType` correspond to keys of `EmailTemplates`, and it can use that relationship to find the value types that are associated with a given `TemplateType`.

```
type EmailTemplates = {
  welcomeEmail: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  };
  referralEmail: {
    referrer: string;
  };
}

type TemplateType = keyof EmailTemplates;

type EmailTemplate<T extends TemplateType> = {
  template: T;
  params: EmailTemplates[T]
}

const myEmail: EmailTemplate<'referralEmail'> = {
  template: 'referralEmail',
  params: { referrer: 'test' },
}
```

There may be some way to infer the TemplateType instead of having to pass it in as a generic type parameter, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

```js
type TemplateType = 'welcomeEmail' | 'referralEmail' | 'loginEmail'

interface WelcomeEmail {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  // ...
}

interface WelcomeEmailTemplate {
  template: 'welcomeEmail';
  params: WelcomeEmail;
}

interface ReferralEmailTemplate {
  // ...
}

interface LoginEmailTemplate {
  // ...
}

type EmailTemplate = WelcomeEmailTemplate | ReferralEmailTemplate | LoginEmailTemplate

const myEmail: EmailTemplate = {
  template: 'welcomeEmail',
  params: {
    // then type checking and hinting is here for WelcomeEmailTemplate
  },
}
```

Comment: This solution still lets you put all the params in without Typescript throwing an error. It requires the 'welcomeEmail' params when set as template but also allows `ReferralEmail` params as well

Comment: sorry about that. I have fixed it